# Texmaker not allowing user-defined shortcuts

Tags: texmaker, mac

I'm using Texmaker on Mac OS 10.8 and I'm generally happy with it. However, I think I noticed a very serious bug:

user defined shortcuts cannot overwrite the default ones, no matter what.
`Cmd`+`shift`+`D` will always mean "subscript" to Texmaker, even though I **removed** that shortcut and made it mean "uncomment" in the preferences.

This is, shall we say, very annoying? I've worked on Kile for Linux for years, and I still do when I'm on a Linux machine at work. I need the freedom to reconfigure shortcuts to mean the same on all editors, regardless of the machine I'm using.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. TeXmaker is cross-platform and can be used on Linux also with latest `4.0.3` version. Hope you are using appropriate [Mac version](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html) on site. Did `TeXmaker--> Configure-->Shortcuts` work ?

Comment: Why don't you post your report on the official Texmaker issue tracker?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried on MacOsX lion and there is no trouble. Cmd+shift+D is assigned to the "uncomment" action if you want :

[image]